# How to change the background of navbar as you scroll using react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am making a website. So, here is my code:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i&subset=devanagari,latin-ext");
body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: 7%;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}

::selection {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0087ff;
}

::-moz-selection {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0087ff;
}

.start-header {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  padding: 20px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 30px 0 rgba(138, 155, 165, 0.2);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.start-header.scroll-on {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(138, 155, 165, 0.15);
  padding: 10px 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.start-header.scroll-on .navbar-brand img {
  height: 24px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.navigation-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  height: 28px;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  filter: brightness(10%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  float: right;
  border: none;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.navbar-toggler:active,
.navbar-toggler:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
  width: 24px;
  height: 17px;
  background-image: none;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  transition: all 300ms linear;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon:after,
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon:before {
  width: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all 300ms linear;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon:after {
  top: 8px;
}

.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"] .navbar-toggler-icon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"] .navbar-toggler-icon:before {
  transform: translateY(8px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"] .navbar-toggler-icon {
  border-color: transparent;
}

.nav-link {
  color: #212121 !important;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.nav-item:hover .nav-link {
  color: #0087ff !important;
}

.nav-link {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 0 !important;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-item:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  content: "";
  background-color: #0087ff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.nav-item:hover:after {
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav-item.active:hover:after {
  opacity: 0;
}

.nav-item {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.full-height {
  height: 100vh;
}

.over-hide {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.absolute-center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 40px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 20;
}

#circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: -11px;
  left: -13px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
}

.switched {
  border-color: #fff !important;
  background: #0087ff !important;
}

.switched #circle {
  left: 43px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 4px rgba(26, 53, 71, 0.25), 0 0 0 1px rgba(26, 53, 71, 0.07);
  background: #fff;
}

.nav-item .dropdown-menu {
  transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.nav-item.show .dropdown-menu {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  max-height: 999px;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
}

.dropdown-menu {
  padding: 10px !important;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #212121;
  background-color: #fcfaff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(138, 155, 165, 0.15);
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-item {
  padding: 3px 15px;
  color: #212121;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.dropdown-item:hover,
.dropdown-item:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0087ff;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-item:after {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-item::before {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 15px;
    left: 0;
    width: 11px;
    height: 1px;
    content: "";
    border: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    vertical-align: 0;
  }
  .dropdown-toggle::after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 10px;
    left: -23px;
    width: 1px;
    height: 11px;
    content: "";
    border: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    vertical-align: 0;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
  }
  .dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]::after {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .dropdown-menu {
    padding: 0 !important;
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
  }
  .dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]+.dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: 10px !important;
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  }
}


/* #Link to page
================================================== */

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all 250ms linear;
}

.logo img {
  height: 26px;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  filter: brightness(10%);
  transition: all 250ms linear;
}

body.dark .logo img {
  filter: brightness(100%);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="navigation-wrap start-header start-style">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">


            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto py-4 py-md-0">
                <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-md-0 ml-0 ml-md-4 active">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Home
                      </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                          Action
                        </a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                          Another action
                        </a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                          Something else here
                        </a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                          Another action
                        </a>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-md-0 ml-0 ml-md-4">
                  <Link className="nav-link" to="/blogs"> Blogs
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-md-0 ml-0 ml-md-4">
                  <Link className="nav-link" to="/contact"> Contact
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-md-0 ml-0 ml-md-4">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Services
                      </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                          Action
                        </a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                          Another action
                        </a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                          Something else here
                        </a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                          Another action
                        </a>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-md-0 ml-0 ml-md-4">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        Journal
                      </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-md-0 ml-0 ml-md-4">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        Contact
                      </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, I have made a navbar. It is transparent. But the thing is, I want it to change color to white as the user scrolls down after a specific div. You can make it white by adding `<div class="navigation-wrap bg-light start-header start-style">` I have no idea how to implement this. I have seen some stackoverflow answers, but none of them work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change Bootstrap navbar color on scroll in React.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60694918/how-to-change-bootstrap-navbar-color-on-scroll-in-react-js)

Answer (score 2):

I only added **javascript** in your code everything else is same

Steps I took:

1. Added a **scroll event listner** to your html.
2. Wrote a condition to **replace** the class name of your element if the vertical scroll amount is greater than **50px**.
3. If not then replace and set your class name to **default**. (helps when you scroll back to top)

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', navScroll);
//adding scroll event listner

function navScroll() {
  if (window.scrollY > 50) {
    // Replace all classes from element after 50px of scroll
    document.getElementById("myNav").className = "navigation-wrap bg-dark start-header start-style";

  } else {
    document.getElementById("myNav").className = "navigation-wrap start-header start-style";
  }
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i&subset=devanagari,latin-ext");
body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: 7%;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
  height: 200vh;
}

::selection {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0087ff;
}

::-moz-selection {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0087ff;
}

.start-header {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  padding: 20px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 30px 0 rgba(138, 155, 165, 0.2);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.start-header.scroll-on {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(138, 155, 165, 0.15);
  padding: 10px 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.start-header.scroll-on .navbar-brand img {
  height: 24px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.navigation-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  height: 28px;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  filter: brightness(10%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  float: right;
  border: none;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.navbar-toggler:active,
.navbar-toggler:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
  width: 24px;
  height: 17px;
  background-image: none;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  transition: all 300ms linear;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon:after,
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon:before {
  width: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all 300ms linear;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon:after {
  top: 8px;
}

.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"] .navbar-toggler-icon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"] .navbar-toggler-icon:before {
  transform: translateY(8px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"] .navbar-toggler-icon {
  border-color: transparent;
}

.nav-link {
  color: #212121 !important;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.nav-item:hover .nav-link {
  color: #0087ff !important;
}

.nav-link {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 0 !important;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-item:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  content: "";
  background-color: #0087ff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.nav-item:hover:after {
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav-item.active:hover:after {
  opacity: 0;
}

.nav-item {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.full-height {
  height: 100vh;
}

.over-hide {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.absolute-center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 40px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 20;
}

#circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: -11px;
  left: -13px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
}

.switched {
  border-color: #fff !important;
  background: #0087ff !important;
}

.switched #circle {
  left: 43px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 4px rgba(26, 53, 71, 0.25), 0 0 0 1px rgba(26, 53, 71, 0.07);
  background: #fff;
}

.nav-item .dropdown-menu {
  transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.nav-item.show .dropdown-menu {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  max-height: 999px;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
}

.dropdown-menu {
  padding: 10px !important;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #212121;
  background-color: #fcfaff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(138, 155, 165, 0.15);
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-item {
  padding: 3px 15px;
  color: #212121;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.dropdown-item:hover,
.dropdown-item:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0087ff;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-item:after {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-item::before {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 15px;
    left: 0;
    width: 11px;
    height: 1px;
    content: "";
    border: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    vertical-align: 0;
  }
  .dropdown-toggle::after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 10px;
    left: -23px;
    width: 1px;
    height: 11px;
    content: "";
    border: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    vertical-align: 0;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
  }
  .dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]::after {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .dropdown-menu {
    padding: 0 !important;
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
  }
  .dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]+.dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: 10px !important;
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  }
}


/* #Link to page
================================================== */

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all 250ms linear;
}

.logo img {
  height: 26px;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  filter: brightness(10%);
  transition: all 250ms linear;
}

body.dark .logo img {
  filter: brightness(100%);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div id="myNav" class="navigation-wrap start-header start-style">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">


            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto py-4 py-md-0">
                <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-md-0 ml-0 ml-md-4 active">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Home
                      </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                          Action
                        </a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                          Another action
                        </a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                          Something else here
                        </a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                          Another action
                        </a>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-md-0 ml-0 ml-md-4">
                  <Link className="nav-link" to="/blogs"> Blogs
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-md-0 ml-0 ml-md-4">
                  <Link className="nav-link" to="/contact"> Contact
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-md-0 ml-0 ml-md-4">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Services
                      </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                          Action
                        </a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                          Another action
                        </a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                          Something else here
                        </a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                          Another action
                        </a>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-md-0 ml-0 ml-md-4">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        Journal
                      </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-md-0 ml-0 ml-md-4">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        Contact
                      </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but the thing is, I am using react. Please ignore the html tags in it

Comment: If you are using functional components in react then just add my javascript code inside your default export function above the return() block and it will work the same, or the more creative way will be to use react framer-motion's useScroll. Hope it helps.